# Is it correct to use two 'which' in one sentence?

Tags: grammar

Could you please tell me if the following sentence is grammatically correct, especially given that I used two "which" in a single sentence?

> "Similarly, x addresses that ...., which echoes y which highlights
> ..."

Comment: Grammaticality doesn't enter into it. Better structuring is ' ... which echoes y. which in turn highlights ... '. Though I'm not sure about the sequentiality of y and z without real-life examples.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with multiple instances of the relativizers ***which*** and ***that*** in a single sentence. Witness [*... the cow with the crumpled horn **that** tossed the dog **that** worried the cat **that** killed the rat **that** ate the malt **that** lay in the house **that** Jack built*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Is_the_House_That_Jack_Built), which would still be perfectly valid with ***which*** instead of ***that*** every time.

Comment: “X, which Y, which *in turn* Z” is my preference since it clarifies that Y->Z rather than possibly X->Z. But it’s not strictly necessary.

Comment: Why was this migrated?  It's a request for simple correctness checking which is explicitly off-topic...